# Cooked rice during rituals

Tags: food, customs

In Karnataka, mainly around Udupi/Mangalore/Sringeri, the cooked rice is called "musure (ಮುಸುರೆ)" (in Kannada). Not sure what it's called in English (may be impure) or Sanskrit.

If cooked rice or rice items offered or touched during the rituals, hand need to be washed before touching anything. At homes as well the cooked rice if served, hand is washed after this. Once we touch dish containing rice (or any boiled item),we are not supposed to touch other items like curd,pickle,salt; rice and non-rice items are kept separate.

It is still good for consumption but hand is washed after touching it. On the other hand, if anything made of wheat or other grains of fine.

Any scriptural references for this type of custom?